# What happens infinite loop in web worker?

Tags: javascript

I write this javascript code.

```
<index.html>
const worker = new Worker('add.js');
worker.postMessage({});
```

```
<add.js>
self.onmessage = () => {
   let sum = 0;
   while(true) {
      sum += 1;
      console.log(sum);
   }
}
```

if run this code, browser freezing.
I don't know what happens, I shouldn't use infinite loop? in web worker? and why?

Comment: Why would one ever need an infanite loop for?

Comment: Might be `console.log(sum);` that's freezing the page, how the console is linked to both process is quite dark-magic.

Comment: I want to calculate continuously, actually I want to calculate raycast in web worker every frame.

Comment: Use [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to execute code on every frame

Comment: @Kaiido I remove console.log(sum) it doesn't freeze, thank you.

Comment: @RickyMo thank you I will use requestAnimationFrame()